# What does this ruby statement means

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I was learning ruby and practicing reverse engineering a ruby app and i found this line :

```
include ::Pro::License
```

I need to know what does it include because I am finding any file or folder name Pro or License

If it was a `class` I want to view the `class`

Comment: `Module#include` is used to put a module on the inheritance chain of a given class - thus giving it access to the methods of that module. As to the rest of the question - there is almost no way for anyone else to know what this module actually does as its application code and not a library or gem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although there exist some conventions for files to be named after the classes/modules they define (and constants autoloading magic, in Rails in particular, relies on these conventions), Ruby itself, as a language, doesn't enforce this in any way. So one can define class `Bar` in `path/to/foo` file, require the latter explicitly and then include `Bar` - everything will just work, for good or bad.

The module you include might be defined in some gem - and some of (most of?) the IDEs don't search the gems source code by default.

So, what to do. If you are on a relatively fresh Ruby (2.7+) there is a [method](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Module.html#method-i-const_source_location) `Module#const_source_location` that can help you to locate where the particular constant comes from (try `self.class.const_source_location("::Pro::License")` in the console). That's probably the shortest path.

If your Ruby is older, try `pry` (or `pry-rails` if it's Rails) [code browsing](https://github.com/pry/pry#code-browsing) capabilities. Drop a breakpoint (`binding.pry`) somewhere in the app, then `cd ::Pro::License`, then `show-source` (dash, not underscore!). It should print the source code of the module along with the full path to the file where it is defined.

If none of the methods above works for you for whatever the reason, then your IDE advanced search (or `grep`) is your only friend (just ensure you're searching not only through the project folder but through gems too).